# Logging in with openbox in Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: openbox

I am installing ubuntu 18.04.4 and plan to use openbox. I have installed openbox, obconfig, and obmenu. The install instructions say to log out and then select openbox from a menu.

My login screen has my name, a text box for the password, a cancel button, a 'wheel' icon and a sign-in box.

When I click on the wheel, I get 2 choices: ubuntu or ubuntu on Wayland.

An option for openbox does not show up.

Is there a way to get to the openbox window manager from the login screen?

Running: `ls -al /usr/share/xsessions/`

gives:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  3 09:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 239 root root 12288 Mar  3 11:30 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   198 May 17  2018 openbox.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   323 May  2  2018 ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   247 May  2  2018 ubuntu.desktop
```

Comment: Please show  `ls -al /usr/share/xsessions/`

Comment: I added your suggestion to my original post.

Comment: Try to reboot if not tried

Comment: Maybe installing `openbox-gnome-session` helps?

Comment: I'm sorry to take so long to respond, but I have been having problems with my internet connection today. Anyway, Gyru, that was the problem. I rebooted and was able to log in.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Per Gryu's suggestion, rebooting solved the issue.